# Magento apptha extension frontend not navigable after installation

Tags: magento2, php, cms, marketplace

I am using the [Apptha](https://github.com/Apptha/Marketplace-M2) module for magento2 , I had installed the module as well and it appears in my admin panel , but when I navigate to *http://localhost:8080/marketplace* , I see this result :

[image]

Apptha module routes is:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
  <router id="standard">
    <route id="marketplace" frontName="marketplace">
      <module name="Apptha_Marketplace" />
    </route>
  </router>
</config>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Did you **enable the module ?** and setup upgrade, cache:clean etc. 
Start your terminal window, then reach at the root of your installed magento project then do this,

```
bin/magento module:enable Apptha_Marketplace
bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento setup:di:compile
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
bin/magento cache:clean
chmod 777 var pub
```

Here in your_project_root>app>etc>config.php file, your module must be set to 1, please check the screenshot.
[image]